# Is there a way to Pass C-PreProcessor definitions To External Tools as Macros?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I have a VS2008 makefile project and would like to pass certain preprocessor definitions (#define) such as HW settings to an External Tool.

Is there any easy way of doing this?  Other than having a middle script that reads .h files for info and passes them to the tool.

something like:

in a .h file you have:
`#define HARDWARE_ADDRESS 0xBEEF`

and call extrnal tool:
program_firmware.exe $(TargetName) HARDWARE_ADDRESS

as opposed to:
program_firmware.exe $(TargetName) 0xBEEF

Comment: Can you turn the problem around?  Create a project property named $(HardwareAddress) and set it to 0xBEEF, then define HARDWARE_ADDRESS=$(HardwareAddress) when you invoke cl?

Comment: I can't modify the .h file(s) and the #defines since they are auto-generated by an app-builder (same with the compiler build file which is not Make).  However, if there's a way to create custom project properties in a makefile project, I might be able to use a vs macro to populate them and call the external tool from the macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can move definition to makefile:

```
h_address=0xBEEF
program_firmware.exe $(TargetName) $(h_address)
CL /DHARDWARE_ADDRESS=$(h_address)  TEST.C
```

The same h_address value is passed both to program_firmware.exe and to C compiler.

Comment: See comments on the question.  also, putting program_firmware.exe call there would run it with every compile which is not something we want.

Comment: If your problem is restricted to some specicic macro, it is not difficult to write a small program that does it. Such tool doesn't need to be complicated as C preprocesor.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Well that would be the middlescript I was trying to avoid.  I ended up using a shell-script with AWK extracting the values and assembling the proper command line.  Windows PowerShell could do the same I guess.